How to write a SELECT Query to get below output
I have 3 tables:

USERS table
enter image description here
USER_SEGMENT_LINK table
enter image description here
SEGMENT table
enter image description here

Please help me to get result shown here, using a SELECT query from these tables:
enter image description here

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Also SSMS is just an IDE (like) application, what database product are you actually using? Tagging SSMS for your Data Engine is like tagging Visual Studio for your programming language; it doesn't really tell us anything.

A solution using STRING_AGG in SQL Server 2017 and later:
SELECT *,(
  SELECT STRING_AGG(segment.NAME, ',') FROM user_segment_link 
    JOIN segment ON user_segment_link.SEGMENTID=segment.SEGMENTID 
    WHERE user_segment_link.USER_ID=users.USER_ID
 ) FROM users

